# clearDB - Mysql - how to set grant priviledges

Tags: mysql, cleardb

I'm creating an event to my CLEARDB mysql database, using heroku server. and I'm using mysql Workbench.

I executed the code

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

and it gives me error of

Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

I tried to set the grant priviledges using this command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

but It prompts me the same erro, access denied.

has anyone here have tried creating events on cleardb mysql database? please advise.

Answer (score 3):

this is the answer I got from clearDB:

> We apologize for the inconvenience, but in shared-resource systems the
>   MySQL configurations are pre-defined and fixed as per best industrial
>   practices, which cannot be modified on per user basis.

this make sense, because i'm using a shared resource so i have to look for an alternative solution to create events.

Comment: Did you find any alternative solution?